# How to resolve the perceptron dilemma for binary classification?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, perceptron

I have a following thought problem involving perceptron and binary classification that I wonder if anyone has thought about before. This is not from any textbook or reference, although I doubt I'm the first one to observe the following.

---

Suppose you wish to do binary linear classification on a separable dataset.

From the famous perceptron convergence theorem (I am referring to the last equation in this document: [http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/courses/6998-2012/notes/perc.converge.pdf](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Emcollins/courses/6998-2012/notes/perc.converge.pdf))

The number of iterations $(k)$ is upper bounded by ,

$$k \leq R^2/\gamma^2$$

Where $R$ is the largest magnitude of your data and $\gamma$ is the margin to the optimal/separating hyperplane.

Now if I wished to increase the rate of convergence of perceptron for finding this optimal hyperplane. This means, I would either increase $\gamma$ or lower $R$.

Since $\gamma$ is an unknown, prior to calculating the optimal hyperplane. Then I can only lower $R$.

I use standardscaler or whatever else technology to normalize my data around the mean and divide by the standard deviation. Great, now $R$ is smaller.

But a problem now arises: the normalized dataset appears to be more "squished" together. This means that my $\gamma$ has also gotten smaller. Hence the bound is now bigger.

**Thenceforth, the perceptron dilemma: should you normalize your data or not?**

Comment: 1. In my view, the 'dilemma' only follows if you grant that the net effect of normalisation is for the bound $R^2 / \gamma^2$ to increase. 2. For this net increase in the bound to occur, it would have to be the case that normalisation would entail a reduction in the margin $\gamma$ that is greater than the reduction in the bound on the Euclidean norm of the data $R$. 3. To me, it is unclear why point 2 would be the case, rather than for the bound $R^2 / \gamma^2$ to be unchanged from normalisation because the reduction in $R$ is *exactly equal* to a reduction in the margin $\gamma$.

Comment: On that basis, my instinct would be that there is no dilemma at all. The intuitive reason why I hold that belief is that "squishing the data" together more closely via normalisation will result in the distance of the closest point to the optimal decision boundary, i.e. the margin $\gamma$, also reducing by exactly the same factor. Meaning that no relative distances are altered - you've just 'zoomed outwards'. However, a full answer to substantiate those intuitive reasons would require a formal derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of trying to reduce $R$ to reduce the bound is interesting, but I do not see a dilemma.

First, lets define each concept precisely. Given a data set $(x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^n$, $x_i \, \in \, \mathbb{R}^k$, $y_i\,\in\,\{-1,1\}$, define $R = \underset{i\,\in\,[n]}{max} ||x_i||$. The theorem states that the perceptron converges for any constant $\gamma > 0$ such that

$$ y_i(x_i\cdot\theta^*) \geq \gamma \quad\forall i\,\in\,[n]\quad,$$

where $\theta^*$ is the optimal hyperplane normalized vector. To have optimal bound, you take $\gamma$ as the largest constant satisfying the inequalities above. Hence, you take $\gamma = \underset{i\,\in\,[n]}{min}||x_i \cdot \theta^*||$, which is called the margin.

Okay, with everything defined, lets tackle the question.

**(Normalization)** First, normalization does not necessarily reduces $R$. Take $x = (x_1, x_2) = (-1/2,1/2)$. That is, $x$ is a sample of size $2$ of a one dimensional vector. The normalized $X$ is either $(-1, 1)$ or $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$, depending on how you compute the standard deviation. Nevertheless, $R$ is smaller for the original $X$ than in the transformed set.

**(A second attempt)** Not wanting to give up, you come up with a simple idea! Just divide the data $x_i$ (all entries of all vectors) by some constant a, arriving at $x_i' = \frac{1}{a}x_i$! This way, the new bound will be $R'= R/a$. Hence, you can make the bound as low as you wish. What happens to $\gamma$, though? Well, the normalized hyperplan vector still is $\theta^*$. hence

$$\gamma' = \underset{i\,\in\,[n]}{min}||x_i'\cdot\theta^*|| = \frac{\gamma}{a} \quad.$$

The upperbound is then

$$ \frac{R'^2}{\gamma'^2} = \frac{R^2}{\gamma^2} \quad,$$

so this idea did not work too.

**(A final thrust)** You decide to bring all your mathematical collection of functions to the table. You think on linear and non linear operators that reduce $R$ greatly but reduces $\gamma$ only slightly. Will you succeed? Maybe. But there is a second tough problem: the original data set $X$ is linearly separable. **You have to find a transformation that, for any linearly separable data set, the transformed data set always will be linearly separable.** If you do not, then the algorithm will not even converge. It is not an easy task to find a transformation satisfying both.